# Замена с помощью jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Не очень хорошо получается у меня с js-ом.

Есть блок с текстом.

```
<div id="4-22" class="element">sample text [ip]100.100.100.100[/ip]</div>
```

Нужно заменить текст с аи пи адресом на ссылку, чтоб вместо

```
sample text [ip]100.100.100.100[/ip]
```

было

```
(body onload) sample text <a href="100.100.100.100">100.100.100.100</a>
```

Скажите, куда копать? Спасибо.

**UPD**
Ребята, подскажите.
Это див у `<div id="4-22" class="element">` меня "кликабельная", т.е при нажатий вызываеться onClick.

Так вот, если нажимаю ссылку, который сделал с помощью скрипта [[@gridsane](/users/7376/gridsane)](/users/7376/gridsane) ,

то оно не переходить по ip адресу, а срабатывает onClick Див блока. Не скажете как обходить ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Почти успел =) Второй вариант с регулярными выражениями (из-за них он может быть медленнее ответа выше.

```
$(function() {
    var target = $("#4-22");
    var html = target.html();
    // заменяем все вхождения на нужную нам строку
    // флаг "g" означает, что заменить нужно все вхождения
    html = html.replace(/\[ip\](.*?)\[\/ip\]/g,"<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>");
    // применяем
    target.html(html);
});
```

[Живой пример jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xTUKm/2/)

**UPD2.** Сделал как в вопросе

Comment: Да, регекспы это хорошо - красивее, если оставлять вариант с парсом строки

Comment: Красивее, но как правило, медленнее

Comment: @gridsane, @Чад, @Asen, спс ))

Answer (score 2):

Получаете значение блока например так (jquery):

```
  block_html = $('#4-22').html();
```

Потом в этом block_html ищете [ip] и [/ip] чем нить типа

```
 startIndex = block_html.IndexOf('[ip]');
 endIndex = block_html.IndexOf('[/ip]');
```

Собираете новую строку из block_html подстроками до startIndex + ваш текст на основе строки из (startIndex,endIndex) + текст после endIndex и полученную строчку фигачете в блок так:

```
$('#4-22').html(parsed_string);
```

Я бы сделал более простое решение, но для этого надо [ip] сделать по другому например:

```
<div id='4-22'>some text <span class="toHref" ip="100.100.100.100"/> some thing other</div>
```

а js по замене такой был бы тогда (не надо париться с парсом строки):

```
$('span.toHref').each(function()
{
  $(this).html("<a href='"+$(this).attr("ip")+"'>"+$(this).attr("ip")+"</a>");
});
```

Можно красивше, но лень.

Answer (score 0):

А почему бы не схитрить? Ведь есть более легкие путь:

```
<div id="4-22" class="element">sample text <ip>100.100.100.100</ip></div>

<script>
var a=$("#4-22 ip").text();  //100.100.100.100
var a=$("#4-22 ip").text("");
var a=$("#4-22 ip").append("<a href='100.100.100.100'>100.100.100.100</a>");
</script>
```

Здесь мы заменили [IP] [/IP] на соответствующие HTML-сущности. Таких тегов в HTML не существует, но jQuery на это плевать =)

Далее чистый jQuery...

Comment: @Asen, а чем это принципиально отличается от моего второго варианта?

Comment: @Чад, извините, не смотрел ответы...